# Replace values in matrix with other values

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix with integers and I need to replace all appearances of 2 with -5. What is the most efficient way to do it? I made it the way below, but I am sure there is more elegant way.

```
a=[1,2,3;1,3,5;2,2,2]
ind_plain = find(a == 2)
[row_indx col_indx] = ind2sub(size(a), ind_plain)
for el_id=1:length(row_indx)
    a(row_indx(el_id),col_indx(el_id)) = -5;
end
```

Instead of loop I I seek for something like: a(row_indx,col_indx) = -5, which does not work.

Answer (score 28):

`find` is not needed in this case.
Use logical indexing instead:

```
a(a == 2) = -5
```

In case of searching whether a matrix is equal to `inf` you should use

`a(isinf(a)) = -5`

The general case is:

`Mat(boolMask) = val`

where  `Mat` is your matrix, `boolMask` is another matrix of `logical` values, and `val` is the assignment value

Comment: @Andrey Can you please also suggest how can this be used when searching for infinity in matrix using isinf function?

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
a(a==2) = -5;
```

The somewhat longer version would be

```
ind_plain = find(a == 2);
a(ind_plain) = -5;
```

In other words, you can index a matrix directly using linear indexes, no need to convert them using `ind2sub` -- very useful! But as demonstrated above, you can get even shorter if you index the matrix using a boolean matrix.

By the way, you should put semicolons after your statements if (as is usually the case) you're not interested in getting the result of the statement dumped out to the console.

Answer (score 1):

The Martin B's method is good if you are changing values in vector. However, to use it in matrix you need to get linear indices.

The easiest solution I found is to use `changem` function. Very easy to use:

`mapout = changem(Z,newcode,oldcode)`
In your case: `newA = changem(a, 5, -2)`

More info: http://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/changem.html

Comment: (PlusOne) Good solution, yet it is worth mentioning that it requires mapping toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a trivial, unoptimised, probably slow implementation of `changem` from the Mapping Toolbox.

```
function mapout = changem(Z, newcode, oldcode)
% Idential to the Mapping Toolbox's changem
% Note the weird order: newcode, oldcode. I left it unchanged from Matlab.
    if numel(newcode) ~= numel(oldcode)
        error('newcode and oldcode must be equal length');
    end

    mapout = Z;

    for ii = 1:numel(oldcode)
        mapout(Z == oldcode(ii)) = newcode(ii);
    end
end
```